# Why can I only have one virtual host?

Tags: apache

My site on http://localhost is just fine. My first virtual host, as specified in `httpd-vhosts.conf` is just fine ... but when I add a second, just a variant with an extra letter tacked on, Apache doesn't seem to try to serve it.

I did restart Apache after editing the file (Xampp on Windows 7)

My `httpd-vhosts.conf` says

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "o:/abc"
    ServerName abc
    ErrorLog "logs/abc-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/abc-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "o:/abc2"
    ServerName abc2
    ErrorLog "logs/abc2-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/abc2-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "f:/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I access http://lcoalhost or http://abc, everything is fine. When I try to access http://abc2 (the local directory does exist) my browser tries to load http://www.abc2.com

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you specify `abc2` in your `hosts` file?

Comment: +1 a very good point, sir! I hope so, but might have overlooked it. I will check when I am next at that PC & get back to you. This certainly smells like the answer.

Comment: d'oh!  Never touch a computer at 3am :-(   Thanks, Roland. That was it